# supremum distance of conjugation and polynomials on the unit circle

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $p(z)\in\mathbb{C}[z]$ be a complex polynomial. I am trying to prove that, in the space of continuous functions on the unit circle $C(\mathbb{T})$, it is $\|\bar{z}-p(z)\|_\infty\geq1$. However I am stuck and I can't think why this should happen. My only idea was that if it was $\|\bar{z}-p(z)\|<1$ then the series $\displaystyle{\sum_{n=0}^\infty(\bar{z}-p(z))^n}$ should converge uniformly on the unit circle and this seems false for some reason. Any hints?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For $|z|=1$ we have
$$
| 1-z p(z)| = | z  \bar z - z p(z)| = | \bar{z}-p(z)| \, .
$$

Therefore the maximum modulus principle applied to $f(z) = 1 - zp(z)$ in the unit disk gives
$$
 1 = |f(0)| \le \max_{|z|=1} |f(z)| = \max_{|z|=1} |1 - zp(z)|
= \max_{|z|=1} |\bar z - p(z)| = \|\bar{z}-p(z)\|_\infty \, .
$$

Comment: Nice answer, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Another approach: Let $p(z)= \sum_{k=0}^{n}a_kz^k.$ On $\mathbb T,$ we have

$$\|z-p(z)\|_\infty = \sup_{t\in [0,2\pi]} |e^{-it} + \sum_{k=0}^{n}a_ke^{ikt}|$$ $$ \ge \left(\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi}|e^{-it} + \sum_{k=0}^{n}a_ke^{ikt}|^2\,dt\right)^{1/2} = (1+ \sum_{k=0}^{n}|a_k|^2)^{1/2} \ge 1.$$